how can I align an image with text in different fonts so that the last text breaks correctly?
I'm having a problem aligning the text with the icon, because the our-numbers-value class has a larger font-size than the our-numbers-text class, so the div ends up growing and the image is aligned with the div.
I used align-items-center in the div with the texts, but when I did that, for some reason, my last text breaks incorrectly, giving me a very unpleasant look.


 .numbers-image {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     margin-right: 15px;
}
 .flex-align-center {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
}
 .text-nowrap {
     white-space: nowrap;
}
 .our-numbers-text {
     color: #061c3d;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 32px;
}
 .our-numbers-value {
     color: #061c3d;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 52px;
}
<div class="flex-align-center">
   <div>
      <img class="numbers-image" src="./assets/svg/paid.svg" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="flex-align-center">
      <span class="our-numbers-text text-nowrap">More then</span>
      <span class="our-numbers-value">0</span>
      <span class="our-numbers-text">
      million in sales of air conditioning equipment.
      </span>
   </div>
</div>



current result:

what I expect:


Try to remove the class flex-align-center from the div that is inside the other div with the same class. It should look like this:
<div class="flex-align-center">
 <div>
  <img class="numbers-image" src="./assets/svg/paid.svg" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div>
  <span class="our-numbers-text text-nowrap">More then</span>
  <span class="our-numbers-value">10</span>
  <span class="our-numbers-text">million in sales of air conditioning equipment.</span>
 </div>
</div>

This way you have two div items inside a flexbox container.

You only want one flexbox, not two.


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #eee;
}

.numbers-image {
  width: 50px;
}

.flex-align-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  background: white;
}

.flex-align-center>* {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.our-numbers-text {
  color: #061c3d;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.our-numbers-value {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: purple;
}
<div class="flex-align-center">
  <img class="numbers-image" src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/06/10/778855_business.svg">
  <div class="our-numbers-text">
    More than <span class="our-numbers-value">10</span>
    million in sales of air conditioning equipment.
  </div>
</div>



